# Error with npm installation while adding a package in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

So I've been trying to install a package that connects the amazon mechanical turk server to my meteor app. The package is called mizzao:turkserver. But I keep getting errors when trying to add the package.

This is the error:
[link to error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slOwW.jpg)

Not quite sure how to get around the issue

EDIT: I'm using Windows 10. Node Version- 4.2.2